# Jenkins maven git hub integration mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: maven, github, jenkins

Hi i am new to this Area i did lot of work on this unable to resolve this

i am integrating my selenium project i stored in git hub and i want to schedule it from localhost jenkins

First i wrote a sample maven project and pushed to git i am configuring jenkins to fetch it from git hub and build on local machine

but i am getting the following error

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\GitJenkinsDemo\workspace
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/chaitanyap97/Gittest.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/chaitanyap97/Gittest.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/chaitanyap97/Gittest.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0ccaf41f5ad97bf665f39b43093f4d94863f824a (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 0ccaf41f5ad97bf665f39b43093f4d94863f824a
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"mvn.bat -f GitTestDemo/pom.xml mvn test && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
'mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE


Configurations are:
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
M2_HOME:C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3
PATH:C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
Or 
PATH:%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

Please help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Maven 3.3.1, the `mvn.bat` file is replaced with `mvn.cmd`. Please refer to [Bug 251213 - new maven command line extension for windows change from .bat to .cmd](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251213).

So please change `mvn.bat` to `mvn.cmd` in your command accordingly.